# Error when installing glass.mapper using nuget package

Tags: glass-mapper

Install-Package Glass.Mapper.Sc -Version 4.4.0.199

I tried to install glass.mapper.sc (4.4.0.199) using the command above but I encounter an error.

[image]

[image: Glass Mapper SC File]

I haven't done anything yet to the files. This is the default.

I also noticed that the reference being added is only castle.core and glass.mapper while in the previous version specifically the version 4.3.4.197 the added references are castle.core, glass.mapper, **glass.mapper.sc and glass.mapper.sc.mvc.**

I think the issue is caused by the missing references **glass.mapper.sc and glass.mapper.sc.mvc.**

Does anyone know how to make it work? Specially how to migrate from version 4.3.4.197 to version 4.4.0.199.

Comment: Did you get any error messages when installing?

Comment: No error message when installing.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is related to following:

- Does your project contain a reference to Glass.Mapper.Sc.dll? If this reference is missing Glass was unable to find the Sitecore.Kernel.dll 
  reference in your project. Add a reference to Sitecore.Kernel.dll and re-install the Glass.Mapper.Sc nuget package.
- Does your project contain a reference to Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.dll? If this reference is missing Glass was unable to find the System.Web.Mvc.dll 
  reference in your project. Add a reference to System.Web.Mvc.dll and re-install the Glass.Mapper.Sc nuget package. You only need to do this if 
  you want MVC support with Glass.*

Comment: It has reference to it.

Comment: same issue - installing from nuget didn't reference those dlls in the solution so manually added it and fixed the issue.  seems odd

Comment: After changing project target framework to be 4.8 had to install System.Web.Mvc.dll. Thanks